# FBLikeControl Not Posting to User's Facebook Page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I am using Facebook's iOS SDK 3.20 to add a like button to my iOS app.  The problem I'm having is that after clicking the button (and then clicking on the OK button on the confirmation screen that is brought up) no post shows up on the user's Facebook page.

Now, it took me a while to get to the point where the confirmation message would come up and not some type of error message.  I had to have my app reviewed by Facebook requesting the "Native Like Button" permission and then make my Facebook app public.

I have reviewed the "Getting Started" guide and the sample apps that come with the Facebook SDK several times and the only thing I'm doing different is setting the objectID of the FBLikeControl to a URL of my choosing (company web site).  Here's my code:

```
FBLikeControl* like = [FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleButton;
like.objectID = @"http://mycompany.com";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:like];
```

All my testing has been done with the XCode Simulator so after clicking the like button the web browser is brought up to show the confirmation.  My only guess right now is that something is not set up right on Facebook's developer web site for the app.

Also, after all the testing I've done, I no longer see the confirmation web page.  The browser is just displayed briefly and the redirects me back to the app.  Here's some logging from after clicking the like button if it helps:

```
2014-11-24 17:31:24.358 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents Persist: Writing 4 events
2014-11-24 17:31:25.933 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents Persist: Read 4 events
2014-11-24 17:31:25.933 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents Persist: Clearing
2014-11-24 17:31:25.934 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBTimeSpentData Restore: {"secondsSpentInCurrentSession":93,"lastSuspendTime":1416873520,"numInterruptions":1}
2014-11-24 17:31:26.137 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: Dynamically loaded library at /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
2014-11-24 17:31:26.137 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: Request <#1125>:
  URL:  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/374418562723727/activities?sdk=ios&advertiser_tracking_enabled=1&bundle_id=com.testapp.liketest&format=json&application_tracking_enabled=1&bundle_version=1.13&event=CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS&url_schemes=%5B%22fb374418562723727%22%5D&advertiser_id=XZF430BA2E-324F-4A4C-95E0-7FC0AD36F3FE&bundle_short_version=13
  Method:   POST
  UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.20.0
  MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
  Body Size:    0 kB
  Attachments:  
    sdk:    ios
    advertiser_tracking_enabled:    1
    bundle_id:  com.testapp.liketest
    format: json
    application_tracking_enabled:   1
    bundle_version: 1.13
    event:  CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS
    url_schemes:    ["fb374418562723727"]
    advertiser_id:  XZF430BA2E-324F-4A4C-95E0-7FC0AD36F3FE
    bundle_short_version:   13
    custom_events_file: <Data - 0 kB>

2014-11-24 17:31:26.138 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBURLConnection <#1128>:
  URL: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/374418562723727/activities?sdk=ios&advertiser_tracking_enabled=1&bundle_id=com.testapp.liketest&format=json&application_tracking_enabled=1&bundle_version=1.13&event=CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS&url_schemes=%5B%22fb374418562723727%22%5D&advertiser_id=XZF430BA2E-324F-4A4C-95E0-7FC0AD36F3FE&bundle_short_version=13'

2014-11-24 17:31:26.240 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBURLConnection <#1128>:
  Duration: 102 msec
Response Size: 0 kB
  MIME type: application/json
2014-11-24 17:31:26.240 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: Response <#1125>
Duration: 102 msec
Size: 16 kB
Response Body:
(
        {
        body =         {
            success = 1;
        };
        code = 200;
    }
)

2014-11-24 17:31:26.240 4MyCabPremium[23014:90b] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents: Flushed @ 1416879086, 4 events due to 'PersistedEvents' - {
    "advertiser_id" = "XZF430BA2E-324F-4A4C-95E0-7FC0AD36F3FE";
    "advertiser_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    "application_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    "bundle_id" = "com.testapp.liketest";
    "bundle_short_version" = 13;
    "bundle_version" = "1.13";
    event = "CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS";
    "url_schemes" = "[\"fb374418562723727\"]";
}
Events: [
  {
    "horizontal_alignment" : "left",
    "_logTime" : 1416879071,
    "object_id" : "http:\/\/mycompany.com",
    "sound_enabled" : true,
    "_implicitlyLogged" : "1",
    "_ui" : "no_ui",
    "style" : "button",
    "auxiliary_position" : "inline",
    "_eventName" : "fb_like_control_impression"
  },
  {
    "horizontal_alignment" : "left",
    "_logTime" : 1416879084,
    "object_id" : "http:\/\/mycompany.com",
    "sound_enabled" : true,
    "_implicitlyLogged" : "1",
    "_ui" : "no_ui",
    "style" : "button",
    "auxiliary_position" : "inline",
    "_eventName" : "fb_like_control_did_tap"
  },
  {
    "horizontal_alignment" : "left",
    "_logTime" : 1416879084,
    "object_id" : "http:\/\/mycompany.com",
    "sound_enabled" : true,
    "_implicitlyLogged" : "1",
    "_ui" : "no_ui",
    "style" : "button",
    "auxiliary_position" : "inline",
    "_eventName" : "fb_like_control_did_present_dialog"
  },
  {
    "fb_dialog_outcome" : "Completed",
    "_logTime" : 1416879084,
    "_eventName" : "fb_dialogs_present_like_og",
    "_implicitlyLogged" : "1",
    "_ui" : "no_ui"
  }
]
Flush Result : Success
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this problem.

Comment: Just because someone likes something doesn't mean it will show up on their timeline

Comment: True, but the FBLikeControl is designed to post to the timeline.  At least, that's what their example app called "ShareIt" does and I've copied the code from that.

Comment: If the user share it it will show up. If the user just likes it it will not.

Comment: Yes, but the "ShareIt" app uses the FBLikeControl as a button.  Which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Then look at what they do to share something. I'm just saying that if someone likes something it will not show up

Comment: Right, I understand what you're saying.  I do want to share a URL not just like.  The FBLikeControl that comes with the latest SDK appears to be doing just that.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLikeControl the first sentence say that it is used for liking an object. If you want to share something use the share dialog that is described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#sharedialog

Comment: Does it show up on their Activity Log ?